# TFS Agent remove from powershell

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, build-agent

My TFS just upgraded to 2017 and I didn't find old agent and system is not allowing me to create new agent unit I remove old one I executed following cmd for remove .\config.cmd then Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > the click enter Failed: Removing agent from the server An error occurred while sending the request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrmoC.png)

could you please me suggest where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message,  it fails because the old build agent is trying to **reach out to the original url to remove itself** from the agent pool. But you have upgraded to 2017 and the TFS server url should be changed or not be reached.

In this case, you could try to Delete/rename the `.agent` file of the old build agent and then try to unconfigure again.

More details please take a look at this similar issue: [Force removal of TFS 2017 build agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957331/force-removal-of-tfs-2017-build-agent)

---

**Update:**

First please make sure you could see hidden files on the build machine, delete the `.agent` and `.credentialsfile`, then call config remove again. This should remove the service from your local machine and will allow you to reconfigure the agent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for updating

Comment: Where I can find .agent find??

Comment: @Shoaibmqureshi Sorry for the later reply, `.agent` file is hidden by default. You need to make sure you could see the hidden files in the file system on TFS build server. Then delete those files and call config remove again. More details please see my update answer.