# How do I reconfigure Azure DevOps agent on server (windows OS)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Agent which was configured to run as service earlier needs to be reconfigured to run interactively.

When I am trying to run agent's `config.cmd` as administrator to reconfigure the agent then a blank window in command prompt opens and gets closed by itself. There is nothing I see more than that.

I want to know the way we can reconfigure the agent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a regular cmd as administrator, then `cd` to the agent folder, then run `config.cmd`.

But when you will do it you will get a message that the agent already configured and you need to remove it and re-configure. so run `config.cmd remove`, after it run again `config.cmd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Do you know how can we check the current configuration of azure devops agent before reconfiguring it?

Comment: Which configuration you need to know?

Comment: I want to know by which user name agent is running on server

Comment: @VaibhavDhasmana Go to the agent pools, there search the agent and check the capabilities

Comment: this doesn't work for me config.cmd remove just hangs

Comment: Removing/renaming the .agent file solved that problem for me, @johnstaveley : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957540/2915851

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
.\config.cmd remove
```